# textareaに特殊文字を入力できないようにする

Tags: wordpress

wordpressでtextareaがいくつかあるのですが、全てのtextareaに特殊文字、改行を入力できないようにするor送信・受取り時に除去する方法はありますでしょうか？

javascriptを使わずにphpで実現したいです。

Comment: 特殊文字とはどういったものを示しますか？

Comment: 有難うございます。<,&,"などです。付け足しになりますが、改行もです。

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[Strip Bad Characters from an HTML PHP Contact Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19167432/9014308)